# How to create url and implement querying firebase node based on url in javascript, (when any page pointing to that url doesn't exist in website)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My wordpress based website simply needs to show profile data on 2 pages.
This profile data is stored in nodes in firebase.

How can I access the profile page via a link like

```
mywebsite.com/<profileId>
```

-this page does not actually exist.

-profileId is node id in firebase

-I wish to use this profileId , to query the specific node and show the object data from that node in the page.

Any keywords, directions, pointers appreciated